# Was antwortet man auf "Wos gibt's niex?"

Tags: grammar, dialect

> Servus! Wos gibt's niex?
>
> Niex.

Ich frage mich, ob es eine richtige Antwort darauf gibt.

Comment: Antworte das, was Du auf "Was gibt es neues?" antworten würdest. Genau das fragt dein Gesprächspartner nämlich.

Comment: Axo. Das ist Boarisch, ja?

Comment: Genauer können das sicher Jan oder Hubert einordnen und zwischen Bayern und Österreich abgrenzen, aber die Richtung stimmt sicher.

Comment: Zwei Fragen: 1.: Aus welcher Region stammen Leute, die das fragen? 2.: Soll »niex« vielleicht eher »nix« heißen (also »nichts«) heißen, oder willst du wirklich ein langgezogenes i andeuten?

Comment: Boarisch ist Bayerisch oda ist das ein anderer Dialekt? Entschuldige mich bitte für meine Dummheit.

Comment: Boarisch ist ein Bayerischer Dialekt, aber auch Tirolerisch oder Steirisch sind Bayerische Dialekte, weil alle in Österreich gesprochenen Dialekte, mit Ausnahme der in Vorarlberg gesprochenen, zu den Bayerischen Dialekten gehören.

Comment: Aso. Das ist was Neues für mich.

Comment: @Stephie: Die Wörter »Wos«, »gibt's« und »nix« (mit sehr kurzem i) gibt es zwar in den Österreichischen Dialekten, aber in dieser Kombination habe ich die drei noch nie gehört. Daher verorte ich den Urheber der Frage in Bayern.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Bauchgefühl stimmt Dir zu, aber was weiß ich als Schwabe schon...? Ich denke "niex" könnte eher "neues" bedeuten, nicht "nix".

Comment: @Stephie: Wenn das der Fall ist (was ich für wahrscheinlich halte, weil dann die Frage auch einen Sinn ergibt), dann reden wir aber eher von einem alemannischen Dialekt als von einem bayerischen. Also das Land der Schwaben, die deutsche Schweiz oder Vorarlberg.

Comment: Ich bin hier mit Hubert auf Linie. *Niex* sieht für mich wie eine verballhornte Form von *nix* aus. Wenn da ein Tippfehler drin ist, und es in Wirklichkeit *Neix* heißt, kann ich was damit anfangen. So nicht. @Stephie

Comment: Übrigens wird von einigen Stellen empfohlen, zwischen *bayerisch* (gehörig zum Freistaat Bayern) und *bairisch* (die Dialekte, die in Altbayern, der Oberpfalz und Österreich ohne Vorarlberg gesprochen werden) zu trennen indem nur ersteres mit *y* geschrieben wird.

Comment: @Jan, du hast recht. Ich habe in meinem Kommentar die falsche Schreibweise verwendet, kann das jetzt dort aber nicht mehr korrigieren. Richtig wäre es so: »Boarisch ist ein *bairischer* Dialekt, aber auch Tirolerisch oder Steirisch sind *bairische* Dialekte, weil alle in Österreich gesprochenen Dialekte, mit Ausnahme der in Vorarlberg gesprochenen, zu den *bairischen* Dialekten gehören.«

Comment: Vote close for off-topic; not about German

Comment: Not about German. Looks like dialect or a German spoken by a gangster.

Comment: Concerning the two preceding comments: German dialects are very much on-topic on this site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ein Problem bei dieser Frage ist, dass es für Dialekte keine Rechtschreibregeln gibt. Unter anderem führt das dazu, dass Laute, in der Standardsprache mit »ks«, »gs« oder ähnlichem wiedergegeben werden, in der Verschriftlichung von Dialektwörtern gerne (aber eben nicht immer) mit »x« geschrieben werden:

> Geselchtes (geräuchertes Fleisch) -> G'söchts -> Xöchts
>   Ein Klacks -> A Klax

Im Fall des Wortes »*nichts*« wird in vielen Dialekten aber aus »chts« derselbe Laut, daher ist »nix« (und nicht »nigs«) die gängige Schreibweise der Dialektform von »nichts«

Das Wort in der Frage enthält aber ein langes i: »niex«. Es wäre aber ungewöhnlich, »nichts« mit langem i auszusprechen, obendrein ergibt der Satz »*Was gibt es nichts*« keinen Sinn, weil er grammatisch falsch ist (sowohl im Dialekt als auch in der standardsprachlichen Übersetzung).

Wenn man aber das *x* durch *gs* ersetzt, und das Wort groß schreibt (weil es sich um ein substantiviertes Adjektiv handelt), wird klarer, wofür »niex« stehen könnte:

> Servus! Wos gibt's Niegs?

Das könnte heißen:

> Hallo, was gibt es Neues?

Dagegen spricht aber, dass »Servus« und »Wos« auf einen bairischen Dialekt hinweisen (Hauptverbreitungsgebiet: Bayern, Österreich), während »Niegs« eher alemannisch klingt, wie man es in der Schweiz oder in Vorarlberg hören könnte. Wörter aus unterschiedlichen Dialektfamilien im selben Satz sind eher ungewöhnlich.

Daher vermute ich zusätzlich noch einen (recht häufigen) Buchstabendreher im letzen Wort: *ie* <-> *ei*. Also:

> Servus! Wos gibt's Neigs?

In einigen Gegenden des bairischen Sprachraums auch:

> Servus! Wos gibt's Neichs?

Die Übersetzung (*Hallo, was gibt es Neues*) bleibt dieselbe, aber jetzt handelt es sich um einen konsistenten Satz, nämlich um einen bairischen, wie man ihn in unterschiedlichen sprachlichen Färbungen in Bayern und in Österreich hören könnte.

Will man darauf antworten, dass es nichts Neues gibt, kann man darauf mit »Nix« (mit kurzem i!) antworten:

> Servus! Wos gibt's Neigs?
>   Nix.

Wenn es aber etwas Neues gab, dann kann man ja das berichten:

> Servus! Wos gibt's Neigs?
>   Da Houns hot si beim Schifoan n Haxn brochn.
>
> Hallo, was gibt es Neues?
>   Hans brach sich beim Schifahren ein Bein.